# Why do the usable sizes differ

Tags: size, android-camera, android-mediarecorder

Again, dont really know how to phrase the question so I will explain.

I have a video recorder application. I open my camera with

```
cameraRecorder = Camera.open(1); //(this is the front facing camera)
```

And get the camera parameters and all supported preview sizes

```
CameraParameters tmpParams = cameraRecorder.getParameters();

List<Camera.Size> tmpList = tmpParams.getSupportedPreviewSizes();
```

one of the preview sizes on the Galaxy Tab 10.1 running ICS (4.0.4) is 800x600

but when I try to set the Video size in my media Player

```
mediaRecorder.setVideoSize(800,600);
```

I get this error:

```
12-19 17:27:55.035: E/CameraSource(110): Video dimension (800x600) is unsupported
12-19 17:27:55.035: E/StagefrightRecorder(110): cameraSource do not init
12-19 17:27:55.035: E/StagefrightRecorder(110): setupCameraSource failed. (-19)
12-19 17:27:55.035: E/StagefrightRecorder(110): setupMediaSource is failed. (-19)
12-19 17:27:55.035: E/StagefrightRecorder(110): setupMPEG4Recording is failed. (-19)
12-19 17:27:55.035: E/MediaRecorder(30119): start failed: -19
```

Does anyone know why this discrepancy might exist (I know one of the supported record sizes is 1280x720 but that is too big for me).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That's because preview and recording is different. You should use the sizes specified in [Camera.Parameters.getSupportedVideoSizes()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/hardware/Camera.Parameters.html#getSupportedVideoSizes%28%29).

```
public List<Camera.Size> getSupportedVideoSizes ()
Gets the supported video frame sizes that can be used by MediaRecorder.
```

Comment: This looks like exactly what I need except I am pushing my app to run for 2.2( froyo) up. and getSupportedVideoSizes() is only for api 11 and up (honeycomb and up).

Comment: Inherit problem is you are targeting a tablet with an old Android release. I think you need to delightfully handle situation and if system provides mentioned method you should honor the fact that preview and record can have different sizes and if the system is old you can rely on the response from the old ways of working.

Comment: Yea i guess Ill have to target api 11 and check if something is gingerbread or below. Thanks